# Unity OnTriggerEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

Anyone can help me how to fix this problem i'm having?

*1st script:

```
public static bool attacking; 
public Collider2D attackTrigger;

private void Awake()
{
    attackTrigger.enabled = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (attacking == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Box Collider Enabled");

        attackTrigger.enabled = true;
        StartCoroutine(DisableCollider());
    }
}

IEnumerator DisableCollider()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    attacking = false;
    attackTrigger.enabled = false;
    Debug.Log("Box Collider Disabled");
}
```

*2nd script:

```
public float damage = .10f;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{  
    if(collision.isTrigger!=true && collision.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy is Damaged");
        EHealthBar.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

i'm trying to get my player character to attack an enemy using collision, well it does work and the player does damage the enemy but it will only work if the enemy's box collider enters my attack again.

if the enemy is already in my area of attack which has a box collision 2d attached, the enemy doesn't get damaged and that's not what i was going for.

I can change it to OnTriggerStay2D but the enemy will keep on getting damaged till the collider is disabled again. care to help?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is

```
    IEnumerator DisableCollider()
    {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    attacking = false;
    ...
```

which causes that your IF statement in your update is still occuring for 1 second and starting a lot of coroutines. The easiest solution would be moving attacking = false; before yield, but i guess you want to use that variable to be aware if user is in attack state. So i suggest to use another bool variable.

```
        if (invokeAttack)
        {
            attacking = true;
            invokeAttack = false

            Debug.Log("Box Collider Enabled");
            attackTrigger.enabled = true;
            StartCoroutine(DisableCollider());
        }
```

Anyway, you didn't show us how you invoke attack, but maybe instead of changing variable (attacking/invokeAttack in your case) to true and checking it in Update you just invoke a method which enables collider and starts coroutine?